# Using Angularjs UI-Grid rowTemplate to get the plus icon in the row header

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a group and subgroup grid using ui-grid v3.0.0-rc.20-8199eb5 - 2015-04-13. I need the plus and minus icon in the rows that contain data and not the grouping header.  Right now there are none in any rows. I have been trying to use rowTemplate and have only been successful in adding another row header but not modifying the existing row header.

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
        enableFiltering: true,
        paginationPageSizes: [25, 50, 75],
        paginationPageSize: 25,
        onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
            var cellTemplate = '<div class="ui-grid-row-header-cell ui-grid-expandable-buttons-cell"><div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><i ng-class="{ \'ui-grid-icon-plus-squared\' : !row.isExpanded, \'ui-grid-icon-minus-squared\' : row.isExpanded }" ng-click="grid.api.expandable.toggleRowExpansion(row.entity)"></i> </div></div>';
            $scope.gridApi.core.addRowHeaderColumn({ name: 'rowHeaderCol', displayName: '', cellTemplate: cellTemplate });
        },
        enableRowSelection: true,
        enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
        enableGridMenu: true,
        multiSelect: false
    };
```

Comment: Can you explain your use case? What exactly are you trying to accomplish by moving the icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject 'ui.grid.expandable' in your module and to add 'ui-grid-expandable' to your ui-grid element like this:

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-expandable class="grid"></div>
```

Use this: http://plnkr.co/edit/0tmCvI05oVNbpfkCquCt?p=preview